# How to disable akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor?

Tags: multithreading, scala, concurrency, akka

I have relatively small parallelization (less than dozen threads) where I want to park all threads simultaneously on some condition (some of them may resume in the course of application, some of them may not).

Because all top invocation are done from akka dispatch which relies onto `BatchingExecutor` invocations are not necessarily batched and the code never reaches the point where all threads are parked at the right place!

```
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch$$Lambda$784/1938142664.apply$mcV$sp(Unknown Source)
at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:81)
at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
```

How I can disable this behaviour?
* I do not have control over wrapped runanble (eg. can't extend from `Batchable`)
* I do not have control execution context, hence cannot use `blocking {}` construct

I simply need configuration option to disable batching/set batch size to `1`.

Answer (score 1):

You should not do blocking on the Akka dispatcher, so 'parking all threads' is not really possible in a meaningful way. I would suggest asking this question in a different way, describing more of your intended use case and constraints: perhaps there is another approach that would fit better.